# How to find these symbols in LaTeX?

Tags: floats, pdftex, symbols

These symbols are in the Word 2010:[image]

Then how should I find them for LaTeX ?

Comment: You can use an editor like [TeXstudio](https://www.texstudio.org/) or [TeXmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) which has a symbol palette.

Comment: Look to fonts like `\mathcal`, `\mathfrak`, the `amssymb` package, as well as the standard LateX math symbols.